# CSS Style Not Populating Correctly

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

I have a flask app I'm building that I'm trying to make look better but the colors aren't populating as expected. Any idea why the colors don't come through correctly. (I've viewed it in IE and Chrome and it's the same).

[image: Example of Output - Colors are not correct]

The folder structure is (there are other HTML files, but they don't matter for recreating the issue):

```
main/site_tables.py
main/templates/view.html
main/static/style.css
```

The python code (site_tables.py) is:

```
#Import various necessary packages
from flask import render_template, Flask, request
import pandas
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
import datetime
import urllib2
import os.path

#Start App from Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

#Set IP Address and Port for outputting web address
out_IP_address = "0.0.0.0"
out_port = 5000

#Set location for original files being read in and edit file locations
#Kept seperate for audit reasons
origLoc = "C:/Orig"
editLoc = "C:/Edit"

#Set name of files prefix
fileName = "Rand_Calls"

#Define holidays for long period of time
cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
holidays = cal.holidays(start='2017-01-01', end='2030-12-31').to_pydatetime()

#Set first empty link - tables
@app.route("/tables/")
#Set dynamically populated links tables/date where date is formatted YYYYMMDD
@app.route("/tables/<date>",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def j_show_html(date):
    #date provided by webaddress for example: date = "20170214"
    #Format date to datetime
    date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%Y%m%d")
    if request.method == "GET":
        #If date hasn't occured; display why missing
        if date2 > datetime.datetime.today()  - datetime.timedelta(days=2):
            return render_template('future.html',
            labels = urllib2.unquote(date.encode('ascii','ignore')))
        #If date was a holiday; display why missing
        elif date2 in holidays:
            return render_template('holiday.html',
            labels = urllib2.unquote(date.encode('ascii','ignore')))
        #If date was a weekend; display why missing
        elif date2.weekday() in (5,6):
            return render_template('weekend.html',
            labels = urllib2.unquote(date.encode('ascii','ignore')))
        #Load report; if not edited before then from original location
        else:
            if os.path.isfile(editLoc+"/"+fileName+"_"+date+"_"+date+".xlsx"):
                report = pandas.read_excel(editLoc+"/"+fileName+"_"+date+"_"+date+".xlsx")
            else:
                report = pandas.read_excel(origLoc+"/"+fileName+"_"+date+"_"+date+".xlsx")
            return render_template('view.html',
            tables=[report.to_html(index=False)],
#            titles = ['na'],
            labels = urllib2.unquote(date.encode('ascii','ignore')))

#Call the app
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host=out_IP_address,port=out_port,debug=True)
```

The HTML file (view.html) is:

```
<!-- Jinja2 code for table page creation -->
<!doctype html>
<title>{{labels}}</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
<div class=page contenteditable="">
  <h1>QA_Report_{{labels}}</h1>
  {% for table in tables %}
    {{ table|safe }}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

The CSS file is (style.css) is:

```
body            { font-family: sans-serif;}
a, h1, h2       { color: #d03027; } /*Color = Specific Red */
h1, h2          { margin: 0; }
h1              { border-bottom: 2px solid #ceccd0; } /*Color - Light Grey*/
h2              { font-size: 1.2em; }

table.dataframe, .dataframe th, .dataframe td 
{
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ceccd0; /*Color = Light Grey*/
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align:left;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}

tr:nth-child(odd)      { background-color:#ffffff; } /*Color = White            */
tr:nth-child(even)  { background-color:#004977; color:#ffffff; } /*Color = Specific Blue */
tr:hover            { background-color:#d03027; } /*Color = Specific Red  */
```

Comment: What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: The same, but the colors designated in the CSS should result in a different visual look. I've commented the CSS to show what the colors should roughly be.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue.

The webpage was being cached. I cleared the browser history and the changes came through. (Reloading the page with Ctrl+Shift+R will allow new changes to come through as well).

Posting this as an answer in case it helps anyone running into the same issue.

Comment: It could have also been that your style.css was not being loaded. In the future, it would be helpful if you posted the structure of the your project and where each file is located.  Additionally, it would be easier for people if you specified the names of the files on the code snippets.

Comment: Thanks. The alternating row colors clued me in that something was being loaded, but I see your points and have updated the question.